# How to make game, made with the BGE, without having to provide source code of the game?

Tags: game-engine, blend-files

The blender FAQ says that if I combine my blend files with blender's game player, my license becomes GPL automatically?

1. Combine? can you explain it more, what combine is talked about here?
2. Is there a way to avoid that without making my own blender player nor using BPPlayer?
3. I also researched something about making a .bat file to launch my game, is that a way to avoid it? How can I protect my .blend files from being read plainly in notepad like apps?

In simple words, I want to make a commercial game in blender and avoid providing the source code (my .blend files).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stand Alone:
The Blender Game Engine is GPLed.  There is not a way to release a game made in the Blender Game Engine without including the Blender Game Engine.  Including the Blender Game Engine makes your game GPLed.

Stand Alone, load external .blend:
You can compile the BGE into a standalone player that loads the .blend of your game, and have the .blend be under a different license.  This would make it illegal for someone else to use your work, but it would trivial for people to break the law and poke at the blend file.

Encrypt:
You could obfuscate the blend file using encryption libraries in python.  The executable which is GPLed would contain the key, and a smart enough dedicated enough person could get at your blend file. It would prevent the average Blender user from being able to steal your assets though.  See: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto for a crypto library.

Practicality (opinions included, sorry):
There is nothing on your computer that you can't "steal" assets of if you are dedicated enough.  There is no way for someone to both have something and not have it at the same time. Stop worrying so much about "theft", and generate a game good enough that people people are willing to pay. If you get big enough where you see large scale copyright infringement, use the DMCA and other copy right laws if you feel the need; but I think you'll find that over enforcing copyright and preventing modding will hurt you in the market place more than a few free loaders abusing your game assets.

Comment: I see, but what I want is that people can only modify the game with a modding application which also I made, I do not want them to modify my game using my game's source code, that GPL wants to publicize

Comment: @nightrobin If you are serious about your game go for Unity or Unreal4, its not that expensive. No pain no gain. I dont think bge is good for serious game development, go for another engine.

Comment: Indeed, there's so real reason to over-think obfuscation.  Just need enough so people know they're not supposed to see it.  And don't even think about relying on obfuscation to protect a flawed multiplayer system.  It will be broken and the game filled with cheats, as always.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if you select user preferences (if it crashes when you go into the one on the toolbar on the top, go into one of your panes and change it to user preferences) select addons and  activate the addon "Export Game Engine Runtime", then from the file menu in the toolbar at the top, select export and select game engine runtime. I did this on 2.72 but it should still work on other versions. But the textures are in Gnu Publsic License, so don't publish it.